# Pass array as argument to Hardhat task

Tags: javascript, hardhat

I'm preparing the task that allows to grant role to addresses from list.

```
const { task } = require("hardhat/config");

task("add_addresses")
  .addParam("rolesControl")
  .addParam("addressesArray")
  .setAction(async (taskArgs, hre) => {
    const rolesContract = await hre.ethers.getContractAt(
      "RolesControl",
      taskArgs.rolescontrol
    );
    await rolesContract.markParticipants(taskArgs.addressesArray);

  });

module.exports = {};
```

I tried to pass the arguments like this

```
npx hardhat add_addresses --network rinkeby --rolescontrol "0xAed7E176616C834a3eF300601D284E95C4302fEf" --addressesArray ["random address"]
```

And received error :

```
Error: invalid value for array (argument="value", value="[0x9d34859383eA75acE0D9415447A47805c62Ba91e]", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.6.2)
```

Need help to figure out how to pass args correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
task("add_addresses")
    .addParam("rolesControl")
    .addVariadicPositionalParam("addressesArray")
    .setAction(async (taskArgs, hre) => {
        console.log(taskArgs)
    })


npx hardhat add_addresses --roles-control 0xAed7E176616C834a3eF300601D284E95C4302fEf address1 address2 address3
```

`taskArgs.addressesArray` will be an array: `["address1", "address2", "address3"]`